# How many monitors can the new retina MacBook Pro handle and at which pixels resolutions?  

Tags: display, macbook-pro

How many monitors can the new retina MacBook Pro handle and at which pixels resolutions?

e. g. Does it support three cinema displays?

Comment: for your info, my mac mini is supposed to be able to have 2 thunderbolt displays, but it works once every month. so what it is supposed to do and what it really does.... cf the faulty dual-DVI adapter that apple still sells. it is totally bugged. everyone knows about it. they still sell it like nothing happens...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Other World Computing Blog [shows that](http://blog.macsales.com/14241-macbook-pro-15-with-retina-display-can-run-3-external-displays) the new MacBook Pro 15" with Retina Display Can Run 3 External Displays:

[image: MacBook Pro 15 with Retina Display Can Run 3 External Displays]

> image source: http://blog.macsales.com/

These resolutions were used:

- Retina on laptop @ “best for Retina”
- iMac used as a display @ 2560 x 1440 via Thunderbolt
- iMac used as a display @ 2560 x 1440 via Thunderbolt/DisplayPort
- LG monitor @ 1920 x 1200  via HDMI

Quote from the [MacRumors news article on that](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/06/20/retina-macbook-pro-can-run-three-external-displays-simultaneously/):

> This makes the Retina MacBook Pro the first Mac -- other than a tower-based workstation like the Mac Pro -- to natively power four displays simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

No, the Macbook Pro Retina can support:

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels **on up to two** external displays, at millions of colors

(emphasis mine)

Source: http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/

**update**: It has been [dully noted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/54306/115) that using the included HDMI connector one can run a third display using a max resolution of 1920 x 1200. 
It is important, however, to note that one cannot daisy chain more than two thunderbolt displays (at least according to Apple so far).

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that when using 60Hz 4K and display port MST on my late 2013 MBP, the "MST" feature actually consumes *both* displayport connectors into a single cable.

So when I enable MST, the second displayport connector goes dead. I have not tried the HDMI connector yet.

Comment: I have now verified with HDMI too; at 60Hz 4K only one *single* display can be connected to my late 2013 15" MBP. The internal retina screen works while the 4K screen is connected. So make your 4K screen large enough :)