# MacBook Pro with retina display external monitor connections

Tags: display, macbook-pro, hdmi, dvi

Is it possible to connect two external monitors to a Retina MacBook Pro without using Thunderbolt displays?

For example, one connected with HDMI and another using [Apple's DVI connector](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB570Z/A) and also use the screen on the laptop.

Comment: I have three DVI monitors attached to mine using adapter cables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that should definitely be possible, as both Thunderbolt ports are also mini DisplayPort ports and the other would be connected via HDMI.

See also this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/54306/14994

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In addition to the HDMI port, you can use either of the Thunderbolt ports as mini DisplayPort ports, just like all Thunderbolt ports.

Comment: Can you confirm both Thunderbolt ports can also act as mini DisplayPort ports - did you possibly try it yourself ?

Comment: It's part of the Thunderbolt spec - all Thunderbolt ports have to act as mini DisplayPorts or they're not Thunderbolt.

Comment: @iolsmit Forgot to tag you on my reply to your comment, and now I can't edit it.

Comment: I can confirm that both Thunderbolt ports on the MBPR are mini DisplayPorts as well. I discovered it by accident and was pleasantly surprised. :-)

Comment: @TheDoctorWhat I would be shocked if they weren't - all Thunderbolt ports are required to be mDP as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this. I have three monitors connected and running in addition to the retina screen. two via the thunderbolt ports and one hdmi

However this caused my retina display to flicker.