# How can I connect a third monitor to my MacBook Pro 13"?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, vga-adapter

I already have one VGA monitor connected to my Macbook Pro's Mini Display Port, but there is only one mini display port on my mac, so I'm not sure how to hook up a second external monitor.  Should I get a VGA splitter and power them both from the one mini display port on my laptop? Should I find a USB to VGA adapter?  USB to Mini Display Port?  Something else entirely?  Please help!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check this question out, looks like a similar question to yours.

[How many monitors can the new retina MacBook Pro handle and at which pixels resolutions?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54078/how-many-monitors-can-the-new-retina-macbook-pro-handle-and-at-which-pixels-reso/54306#54306)

Also, more specifically this:

[How many monitors can the 13" retina MacBook Pro output to?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87712/how-many-monitors-can-the-13-retina-macbook-pro-output-to)

Seems you need Thunderbolt and HDMI to do it. And if you're talking about the latest MBP 13" then you may be out of luck as that only has a single Thunderbolt port.

If you are on the new model you can't get more than one external display going without daisy-chaining through Thunderbolt which will cost you a bit unless you already have compatible monitors and hardware. DVI/HDMI/VGA won't cut it.

THOUGH...

If you wanted to go through USB apparently this is also an option:

https://gigaom.com/2010/10/07/quick-tip-add-more-external-displays-to-your-mac/

Buy a USB to DVI adapter, install DisplayLink drivers, and good luck

Comment: This is incorrect, the retina 13" has two Thunderbolt ports and OS X can output simultaneously on two external displays on both ports, or on a combination of Thunderbolt and HDMI.

Comment: @bain, the retina MBP does have two thunderbolt ports, but the non-retina model only has one. cs. did not specify retina or not. check out https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/ & https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs-retina/